# how to get words from a sequence of characters in java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, character

I have a method getNextChar() which reads a string character by character. And I am writing a method to get the words in a character sequence provided by getNextChar().

The text contains punctuation marks and other special characters.

I am thinking to have an array which contains all the punctuation marks and special characters, and when I read the characters of the text, check if the character is in the array to ignore it. 
The method will recognize the word when it get's a space. **The words will be stored in a Collection** (ex: map) as i need to **count the frequencies** as well by checking if the word has been inserted before in the map and increasing the counter of that word.

1. Is this the best and **efficient** way of doing it? I am looking for the **most efficient way**. A
2. Is there any **complete list of punctuation marks and special characters**?

Comment: are you only getting your data a character at a time?  Or are you getting it a string at a time, and you were merely choosing character iteration because that was what you thought was the best way to find word breaks?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html  this probably can do what you're attempting to

Comment: I am getting one character a time , till i get EOFException when there are no more chars.

Comment: For the list of punctuation marks and special characters would be useful to know wich language are you processing.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an easier way to do this.

No matter what your input source is, I would be reading it using the Scanner class. You can instantiate this class using your input string and call the Scanner.nextWord() method to get the next word in the string. This automatically checks for whitespace and returns the next word. Then, you can use String.replace("punctuation","") to remove punctuation and then insert these words into an ArrayList and you can count frequencies etc.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(string);
String word = reader.nextWord();
word=word.replaceAll(//code);
list.add(word);
```

Comment: You could also change the delimiter Pattern of the Scanner using `usePattern()` to match any sequence of whitespace or word-separating punctuation marks (being careful not to include the hyphen)

Comment: Good idea, that would help with specificity

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.split() to break apart the string into an array of strings separated by whitespace (for your words.)  You could also check each character with Character.isLetterOrDigit() to avoid punctuation.  (Not necessarily in that order.)

Comment: This isn't the most "efficient" way though. It requires reading the entire string and *then* parsing the words. The OP wants a way to do this in place.

Comment: Ah! Sorry.  I read "best" and my mind skipped the "efficient".  Often the two are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup for punctation will have a better performance if you use a Set of characters.

```
Set<Character> punctationchars ....
if(punctationcahars.contains(yourChar) { ... }
```

Comment: If the number of characters is small, the difference between `O(n)` lookup of an array and `O(1)` lookup of a hashtable is basically the same. It depends how many characters there are I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Scanner` to read in the `String`s:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(...);

while (in.hasNext()) {
    String word = in.next();
    /* do something with the word, check punctuation, etc. */
}
```

Comment: but this requires parsing all the characters and generate a string from it.. does not sound efficient.